# Azure Cognitive Search Throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to use the Azure Cognitive Search UI. I have cloned the repository for the Knowledge Mining solution accelerator (git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-knowledge-mining.git). When running the solution, it throws a system null reference exception (Object reference not
set to an instance of an object) pointing out the Home Controller file.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Can you show the code where the error occurs?

Comment: See the code below, 
`public ActionResult Suggest(string term, bool fuzzy = true)
        {
            var response = _docSearch.Autocomplete(term, fuzzy);

            List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
            if (response != null)
            {
                foreach (var result in response.Results)
                {
                    suggestions.Add(result.Text);
                }
            }`

Comment: See the exception and code below, 
> System.NullReferenceException
>  HResult=0x80004003
>Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Source=CognitiveSearch.UI
> StackTrace:
> at CognitiveSearch.UI.Controllers.HomeController.Suggest(String term, Boolean 
> fuzzy) in C:\Users\***\source\repos\azure-search-knowledge-mining\02 - Web UI 
> Template\CognitiveSearch.UI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 182

Comment: sorry about the formatting but I'm new using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The type of error you mention are almost always caused by some sort of issue with the appsettings.json file where the servicename/api key/ etc. are set. One good way to debug is to put a breakpoint in the constructor of DocumentSearchClient.cs. on lines 59 and 81. There you can catch potentially catch the error and then dig into the inner exception.

If the debugging doesn't reveal the problem, do raise an issue on the git repo.

Comment: Thanks Sophiac!!! it was an issue with appsettings.json and public access to the azure blob container